# Laravel blade: if..else statement behaves unexpectedly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Sorry, I couldn't find a better title for this question.

I want to show "follow" **or** "Edit Profile" link, depends on whether authenticated user is watching his own profile or other user's profile.

Here is my blade code:

```
@if(isLogedIn())
    @if($authedUser->id !== $profile->user()->find(1)->id)
        {{link_to_action('RelationshipsController@add', 'Follow', $profile->user()->find(1)->id, ['class' => 'button radius'])}}
    @else
        {{link_to_action('ProfilesController@edit', 'Edit Profile', $authedUser->id, ['class' => 'button radius'])}}
    @endif
@endif
```

Now, if I am watching other users' profiles everything is fine(`if` statement just works and I can see `Follow` link), However if I try to watch my own profile, laravel throws an exception : `Trying to get property of non-object`. The thing here is that `$profile->user()->find(1)->id` throws that exception, because when I hardcoded that to an integer everything worked properly.

Here is the line which causes the exception:

```
<?php if($authedUser->id !== $profile->user()->find(1)->id): ?>
```

PS1: The problem is not nested `if`s.

PS2: In this situation my code never touch `else` part.

**EDIT:**
Here is ProfileController@show :

```
public function show($userId)
{

    try{
        $profile = $this->profileRepo->byForeignKey('user_id',$userId)->firstOrFail();
    }catch(ModelNotFoundException $e){
       throw new ProfileNotFoundException('profile not found');
    }
    return View::make('profiles.show')->with('profile', $profile);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's because `$profile->user()->find(1)` returns `null`. Why do you need `find(1)` anyways?

Comment: `{{dd($profile->user()->find(1)->id)}}` before `if` throws same exception. I think there is something wrong with my ProfileController, but I can't understand what is it.

Comment: because I need user's `id`. `$profile->user()` returns BelongsTo object so I used `find(1)` to get User object.

Comment: Does `$authedUser` variable exists in this context?

Comment: @Volvox yes it exists. BTW, the problem was that `find` methods which looks for `id=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments: "because I need user's id. `$profile->user()` returns BelongsTo object so I used `find(1)` to get User object."

In this case you can use the dynamic property `user` instead of calling `user()`.

```
@if($authedUser->id !== $profile->user->id)
```

Which is the same as

```
@if($authedUser->id !== $profile->user()->get()->id)
```

But you can't use `find(1)` here. It will try to search for an object with `id = 1`